# How to play only the audio of a Youtube video using HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, youtube

Is it possible to play only the audio from a YouTube video using HTML 5 and Javascript?

Comment: youtube serves videos, thus only videos stream from their servers not unless they have an audio only option which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Embed the video player and use CSS to hide the video. If you do it properly you may even be able to hide only the video and not the controls below it.

However, I'd recommend against it, because it will be a **violation of [YouTube TOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)**. Use your own server instead if you really want to play only audio.

Comment: It is against the TOS: `[Prohibited] separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;` http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/terms.html

Comment: ok then..i'll just upload the video with a black image and use a black background :D

Comment: does that really violates YouTube TOS. As far as I understand, the TOS talks about its API only. Embedding the video player and using css to hide video does not use the YouTube API. So I think it does not violates the YouTube TOS.

Comment: So yeah, this is a solution but what about YouTube video ads?  Even if you have it as background music, the user would be bombarded by hidden audio ads.

Comment: @PeteAdamBialecki you can use ad blocker or adblock browswer

Comment: do you have practicle example ? thanks

Comment: **UPDATE JUN 2022** Nothing works for me so I decide to build look for another solution and found this: https://codepen.io/gaffling/pen/YzebyrE

Answer (score 45):

**UPDATE 2022**

webm formats added for demo. You can always check for console log and add all formats needed.

**UPDATE 2021**

You can parse Youtube HTML page for all streams available for this particular video and extract audio only streams.

Here is an example with public Google Image proxy (but you can use any free or your own `CORS` proxy):

```js
var vid = "3r_Z5AYJJd4",
  audio_streams = {},
  audio_tag = document.getElementById('youtube');

fetch("https://images" + ~~(Math.random() * 33) + "-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en&v=" + vid)).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.text().then(data => {

      var regex = /(?:ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*|ytInitialPlayerResponse\s?=\s?)(.+?)(?:;var|;\(function|\)?;\s*if|;\s*if|;\s*ytplayer\.|;\s*<\/script)/gmsu;

      data = data.split('window.getPageData')[0];
      data = data.replace('ytInitialPlayerResponse = null', '');
      data = data.replace('ytInitialPlayerResponse=window.ytInitialPlayerResponse', '');
      data = data.replace('ytplayer.config={args:{raw_player_response:ytInitialPlayerResponse}};', '');


      var matches = regex.exec(data);
      var data = matches && matches.length > 1 ? JSON.parse(matches[1]) : false;

      console.log(data);

      var streams = [],
        result = {};

      if (data.streamingData) {

        if (data.streamingData.adaptiveFormats) {
          streams = streams.concat(data.streamingData.adaptiveFormats);
        }

        if (data.streamingData.formats) {
          streams = streams.concat(data.streamingData.formats);
        }

      } else {
        return false;
      }

      streams.forEach(function(stream, n) {
        var itag = stream.itag * 1,
          quality = false;
        console.log(stream);
        switch (itag) {
          case 139:
            quality = "48kbps";
            break;
          case 140:
            quality = "128kbps";
            break;
          case 141:
            quality = "256kbps";
            break;
          case 249:
            quality = "webm_l";
            break;
          case 250:
            quality = "webm_m";
            break;
          case 251:
            quality = "webm_h";
            break;
        }
        if (quality) audio_streams[quality] = stream.url;
      });

      console.log(audio_streams);

      audio_tag.src = audio_streams['256kbps'] || audio_streams['128kbps'] || audio_streams['48kbps'];
      audio_tag.play();
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<audio id="youtube" autoplay controls loop></audio>
```

Doesn't work for all videos, very depends on monetization settings or something like that.

Comment: nice answer. the herokuapp eas new to me, the CORS was the problem that couldnt be beaten with javascript, but that method solves the problem.

Comment: It would be nice to present example codes without JS libraries, if they are not really required.

Comment: It works but I think you are missing something from the video info... like the signature.

Comment: It looks like YouTube changed the `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` and `adaptive_fmts` in September 2019.  See my post below...  I modified your solution a bit to get it working.

Comment: bxnYFOixIoc for this youtube id your code did not work as it contained not url. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir For this specific video there is no mp3 formats in meta response. Its depends on user agent I guess or something else. Webm streams available in console of needed.

Comment: @350D i can use webm in place of mp3 audio to play audio you mean to say? i tried some links and it did not work so I thought may be after your answer something has already changed in the youtube website. I try if I can use webm to play only audio. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir You can use webm link in supported browsers only (Firefox for example)

Answer (score 9):

### UPDATED FOR 2020

It seems in Septeber 2019, [YouTube updated the values](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/486) that are returned by `get_video_info`.

Rather than `data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` and `data.adaptive_fmts` (as used in the other older examples) now we are looking for for `data.formats` and `data.adaptiveFormats`.

Anyways here is what you are all here for **some code that loads a YouTube video into an `<audio>` element**.  [Try it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/joshstovall/pen/mdPYbJG)

```js
// YouTube video ID
var videoID = "CMNry4PE93Y";

// Fetch video info (using a proxy to avoid CORS errors)
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + videoID).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.text().then(ytData => {
      
      // parse response to find audio info
      var ytData = parse_str(ytData);
      var getAdaptiveFormats = JSON.parse(ytData.player_response).streamingData.adaptiveFormats;
      var findAudioInfo = getAdaptiveFormats.findIndex(obj => obj.audioQuality);
      
      // get the URL for the audio file
      var audioURL = getAdaptiveFormats[findAudioInfo].url;
      
      // update the <audio> element src
      var youtubeAudio = document.getElementById('youtube');
      youtubeAudio.src = audioURL;
      
    });
  }
});

function parse_str(str) {
  return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
    var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
      return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
    });
    params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
    return params;
  }, {});
}
```

```html
<audio id="youtube" controls></audio>
```

Comment: any idea why it's not working for me? also the code snippet here is not working. It just shows an audio player, without playing anything. In the console you get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden, see https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo)

Answer (score 9):

You can make a fake audio player to toggle the Youtube iframe through Youtube Iframe API,
and also use the API to get informations that you want to display on your audio player.
Here is my example.

###### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script src="player.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Youtube-->
    <div id="player" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div>
    
    <!--Player-->
    <div class="audio-player">
        <div class="player-controls">
            <div id="radioIcon"></div>
            <button id="playAudio"></button>
            <div id="seekObjContainer">
                <div id="seekObj">
                    <div id="percentage"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p><small id="currentTime">00:00</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

###### player.js

```js
var player;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    document.getElementById(ui.play).addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
    timeupdater = setInterval(initProgressBar, 100);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        document.getElementById(ui.play).classList.remove('pause');
        document.getElementById(ui.percentage).style.width = 0;
        document.getElementById(ui.currentTime).innerHTML = '00:00';
        player.seekTo(0, true);
    }
}

let ui = {
    play: 'playAudio',
    audio: 'audio',
    percentage: 'percentage',
    seekObj: 'seekObj',
    currentTime: 'currentTime'
};

function togglePlay() {
    if (player.getPlayerState() === 1) {
        player.pauseVideo();
        document.getElementById(ui.play).classList.remove('pause');
    } else {
        player.playVideo();
        document.getElementById(ui.play).classList.add('pause');
    }
}
        
function calculatePercentPlayed() {
    let percentage = (player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration()).toFixed(2) * 100;
    document.getElementById(ui.percentage).style.width = `${percentage}%`;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
    const currentMinute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60;
    const currentSecondsLong = currentTime % 60;
    const currentSeconds = currentSecondsLong.toFixed();
    const currentTimeFormatted = `${currentMinute < 10 ? `0${currentMinute}` : currentMinute}:${
    currentSeconds < 10 ? `0${currentSeconds}` : currentSeconds
    }`;
    
    return currentTimeFormatted;
}

function initProgressBar() {
    const currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(player.getCurrentTime());
    document.getElementById(ui.currentTime).innerHTML = currentTime;
    document.getElementById(ui.seekObj).addEventListener('click', seek);

    function seek(e) {
        const percent = e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
        player.seekTo(percent * player.getDuration());
    }
    
    calculatePercentPlayed();
}
```

###### player.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-size: 6px 6px !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 46%, coral 49%, coral 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%);
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.audio-player {
    width: 470px;
    padding: 35px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.audio-player .player-controls {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.audio-player #radioIcon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url("https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/microphone.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
.audio-player #playAudio {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url("https://img.icons8.com/play") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
.audio-player #playAudio.pause {
    background: url("https://img.icons8.com/pause") no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}
.audio-player p {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.audio-player p small {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.audio-player #seekObjContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
.audio-player #seekObjContainer #seekObj {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.audio-player #seekObjContainer #seekObj #percentage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: coral;
}
```

The audio player came from [here](https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/MBNBEW).
Hope this could help you guys!!

Answer (score 8):

This may be an old post but people could still be searching for this so here you go:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:267px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:-276px;left:-5px">
<iframe width="300" height="300" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeID?rel=0">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

VIDEO_ID with actual ID of your YouTube video.

```
<div data-video="VIDEO_ID"  
        data-autoplay="0"         
        data-loop="1"             
        id="youtube-audio">
 </div>

 <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to start and stop the audio at specific times? What are the attributes to be used?

Comment: You can achieve this by adding these query params in the youtube url: `start=00:30&end=03:20`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple:
Use a 3rd party product like jwplayer or similar,
then set it to the minimal player size which is the audio player size (only shows player controls).

Voila.

Been using this for over 8 years.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: SUre it does. It lets us know that jwplayer is a viable alternative.

Comment: It's not a viable alternative "using html5 and javascript".

Comment: Does this still cost you data for streaming a video ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom van der Woerdt. You could use CSS to hide the video (visibility:hidden or overflow:hidden in a div wrapper constrained by height), but that may violate Youtube's policies. Additionally, how could you control the audio (pause, stop, volume, etc.)?

You could instead turn to resources such as http://www.houndbite.com/ to manage audio.

Comment: other resources seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the mentions of jwplayer and possible TOS violations, I would like to to link to the following repository on github: [YouTube Audio Player Generation Library](https://github.com/navarr/ytaudio/), that allows to generate the following output:

[image]

Library has the support for the playlists and PHP autorendering given the video URL and the configuration options.

Comment: It's a nice link, but it uses Flash Player, not HTML5.

Comment: @mbomb007, good catch, totally forgot about HTML5 in the title! I'll leave the answer though as people might still land on this page if they don't have an HTML-only requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vid = "bpt84ceWAY0",
    audio_streams = {},
    audio_tag = document.getElementById('youtube');

fetch("https://"+vid+"-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?container=none&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fget_video_info%3Fvideo_id%3D" + vid).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.text().then(data => {

            var data = parse_str(data),
                streams = (data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map + ',' + data.adaptive_fmts).split(',');

            streams.forEach(function(s, n) {
                var stream = parse_str(s),
                    itag = stream.itag * 1,
                    quality = false;
                console.log(stream);
                switch (itag) {
                    case 139:
                        quality = "48kbps";
                        break;
                    case 140:
                        quality = "128kbps";
                        break;
                    case 141:
                        quality = "256kbps";
                        break;
                }
                if (quality) audio_streams[quality] = stream.url;
            });

            console.log(audio_streams);

            audio_tag.src = audio_streams['128kbps'];
            audio_tag.play();
        })
    }
});

function parse_str(str) {
    return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
        var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
            return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
        });
        params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
        return params;
    }, {});
}
```

```html
<audio id="youtube" autoplay controls loop></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, you can set the video's brightness to zero and the video area will go all black while the controls remain visible...

Via CSS...

```
 filter: brightness(0%);
```

Via JS...

```
 V.style.filter='brightness(0%)';
```

**NB:** Normal default value for brightness is 100%.

Comment: While that may work, it's very inefficient when it comes to data usage, as the video data will still load in the background, and is much more data-heavy than the audio.

Answer (score -2):

```js
// YouTube video ID
var videoID = "CMNry4PE93Y";

// Fetch video info (using a proxy to avoid CORS errors)
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + videoID).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    response.text().then(ytData => {
      
      // parse response to find audio info
      var ytData = parse_str(ytData);
      var getAdaptiveFormats = JSON.parse(ytData.player_response).streamingData.adaptiveFormats;
      var findAudioInfo = getAdaptiveFormats.findIndex(obj => obj.audioQuality);
      
      // get the URL for the audio file
      var audioURL = getAdaptiveFormats[findAudioInfo].url;
      
      // update the <audio> element src
      var youtubeAudio = document.getElementById('youtube');
      youtubeAudio.src = audioURL;
      
    });
  }
});

function parse_str(str) {
  return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
    var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
      return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
    });
    params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
    return params;
  }, {});
}
```

```html
<audio id="youtube" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ! Include some context and explanation about your solution !