# Make YouTube video quality as low as possible when out of view range

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

### Question

So I want to have embedded YouTube videos. But when you scroll down it's just gonna use the sound and put `fixed` controls on the bottom of the page.

When you don't see the video anymore but just use it as sound, the quality of the video doesn't matter, so to not drain someone's internet, can I change the YouTube video's quality to the lowest possible (144p) with YouTube ? It should still be possible to change the YouTube video to its old quality when you scroll back up.

---

### Not part of the question, but if you know this you can help me out :)

> In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690255/how-to-play-only-the-audio-of-a-youtube-video-using-html-5)  post I saw its not allowed to
>   just have the controls of the Youtube video to use it for audio. But
>   if I do it this way where I still use the video but when off the screen just 
>   use the sound. Is this allowed?

Comment: Try **`getAvailableQualityLevels()`** to see all available quality level for your video then use **`setPlaybackQuality()`**, follow the documentation about [Playback quality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality). Hope this helps.