# Live Streaming Video to audio wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have a YouTube channel that I often live stream to. This channel is embedded on my website for users on site to see. Many want an audio live stream as well. So is it possible to push my video stream to an audio player which will then play live stream as an audio? Or is there another way around this without having to make two separate streams?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play only the audio of a Youtube video using HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690255/how-to-play-only-the-audio-of-a-youtube-video-using-html-5)

Comment: You can't reasonably do this with YouTube without wasting a ton of bandwidth, and you'll get better quality if you make an audio-only stream to some other service anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third-party plugin would be needed for this.
You can try using [WP YouTube Lyte](https://sl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte) plugin, with which you can embed only audio of a Youtube video.

It shows it somehow likes this:
[image]

This would be the easiest and most safe way as far as I know.

Comment: A third-party plugin isn't strictly required.  This is Stack Overflow, where we can show how to code things.

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. I provided an answer to the question which worked for me too. It got him into the right direction how to do this - he didn't specifically mention he wanted to code this. If someone wants to show him how to code this, you are more than free to write a new answer and teach him how to do it.