# Play Live Streaming Video on Youtube into Audio stream on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, audio, youtube, streaming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a channel I stream Youtube videos to.
I am looking for a way to convert my live streaming on Youtube into Audio format on my Wordpress Website.

I did come across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449099/live-streaming-video-to-audio-wordpress)  which uses the [WP YouTube Lyte](https://sl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-youtube-lyte/) plugin.

Also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690255/how-to-play-only-the-audio-of-a-youtube-video-using-html-5) which uses HTML5 & javascript.
These are good solutions, but I am wondering if there are any way or solutions which would make the **audio player full screen**, *(the audio streaming will be played on a mobile platform only)* 
and also maybe pull in the cover art of the streaming.