# "ng new app-name" results in "npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: angular-cli, angular6

On a Mac, I’m trying to follow the steps in the Angular.io tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)

```
$node -v
v8.11.4

$npm -version
6.4.1

$npm install -g @angular/cli
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
+ @angular/cli@6.2.3
updated 1 package in 6.533s

$ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
CREATE angular-tour-of-heroes/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (318 bytes)
CREATE angular-tour-of-heroes/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/XXXXXX/.npm/_logs/2018-09-25T19_56_34_147Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

I’ve tried this a few times. Why do I keep getting the error message `npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded` on running `ng new angular-tour-of-heroes`?

Comment: clean an npm cache and try command - npm cache clean --force

Comment: Thanks @HrishikeshKale, but that didn't help. Same error persists after running your command.

Comment: can you follow this step and confrim npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: No luck @HrishikeshKale: I tried 1) npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 2) npm cache clean --force 3) npm install -g @angular/cli@latest 4) ng new angular-tour-of-heroes --force -> Exact same result as shown above

Comment: Solution Found -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5328#issuecomment-429148117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the answer to the above problem -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5328#issuecomment-429148117

The culprit was .npmrc file that was located in user home dir Users/you/.npmrc. Once I removed the files, all was well.

Comment: hi did you ever figure out how to add start times, what about a seek bar? on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597384/10431770

Answer (score 3):

I am also facing same issue. But after long time i found that this is because of version problem. I updated node, npm and angular/cli to the latest version then this issue get resolved. 
To update npm use this command

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

To update angular/cli use this command

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean (or)  npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

After that it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem on Windows 10, working with node-v11.14.0-win-x64 zip install.

Tried both answers on this page:

1. ~/.npmrc file to be deleted --  did not exist at location
2. Udating npm (6.7.0 to 6.9.0) & reinstalling angular/cli (went from 7.3.8 to 7.3.9)

No luck.
What worked for me was:

1. $ npm cache clean --force
2. installing LTS version: node-v10.15.3-win-x86 (again zip install).
   (Update path in .bashrc to point to LTS node distro)
3. noticed a node_modules & package-lock.json under my development source tree -- deleted these as well.

(Instead of installing angular/cli and typescript again, simply copied over those directories from node_modules of 11.14 to the one under 10.15.
Ditto for the ng, tsc, tsserver & .cmd files)

And then ng new app-name worked.
So between choosing the node LTS version and cleaning the cache something worked.

Had this not worked, I would've tried [installing YARN](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5328#issuecomment-429154182)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me please try below -

`.npmrc` file to be deleted from `C:\Users\you`