# How to use WriteStream with Svelte api endpoints

Tags: node.js, streaming, svelte, html5-audio, sveltekit

I am using [youtube-audio-stream](https://github.com/JamesKyburz/youtube-audio-stream), and want to use it to stream Youtube audio directly to an `audio` html tag. It has a 'stream' function that returns a [`WriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fswritestream). The usage in express is like this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601119/stream-audio-from-youtube-to-an-html-audio-tag)):

```js
const stream = require('youtube-audio-stream');

const uri = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1TcDHrkQYg";

app.get("/stream", (req, res) => {
  stream(uri).pipe(res);
})
```

How can I do the equivalent in svelte kit api endpoints? The [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) gives example of ReadableStream but not WriteStream.