# I want a YouTube audio to play in the Background of my web-page

Tags: html, audio

As our Homework we have to do a html WhatsApp Multiple choice story and for a joke i want a YouTube video to play in the Background i have put this in the header but it wont play

```
<audio autoplay hidden>
         <source src="https://youtu.be/NAh9oLs67Cw" type="audio/mpeg">
                    If you're reading this, audio isn't supported. 
        </audio>
```

Comment: Dubplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690255/how-to-play-only-the-audio-of-a-youtube-video-using-html-5/45375023

Answer (score 0):

To get started, simply paste the code below near the opening  tag of your web template. You should also replace the ID with the actual video ID of the YouTube video that you would like to use in the background.

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

// Replace ID with the actual ID of your YouTube video

The trick is that you embed a regular YouTube video (with autoplay=1) and set the height & width of the video player to zero so the embedded IFRAME element stays invisible. This can be achieved with a single line of code that you can add anywhere on your web page.

```
<embed height="0" width="0"
  src="http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1&loop=1" />
```