# Is there a way to play audio on website with user inputted Youtube URL's?

Tags: javascript, url, audio, youtube

Is there a way to play music on a website using only a URL to a Youtube video/playlist? (Similar to how you can play and queue music using a discord music bot.) I am hoping to allow the user to input a Youtube URL and have my audio player play the audio of the video.

I have tried looking into libraries and such that would help with this, but there is very little on the subject. I've also looked into discord.js, and although I don't understand it fully, I am unsure if it will be compatible for making something not associated with discord.

EDIT: I am using the audio tag in order to play music and 2 libraries that I am using 2 other web APIs that depend on the audio tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play only the audio of a Youtube video using HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690255/how-to-play-only-the-audio-of-a-youtube-video-using-html-5)

Comment: I appreciate very much appreciate the help. However, I think that the way I am trying to approach this problem makes it impossible. I am currently using an audio tag in order to play mp3 files of my choice, and then implementing 2 audio analyzer libraries in order to extract frequencies. Since there doesn't seem to be a way to embed youtube URL's into the HTML audio tag, my audio analyzer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Full answer :)
Note that it plays the particular video, no way you can do that with audio (as much as i know and as much as i can)

```
<input id="videourl"><button onClick="do()">Load</button>
<video id="video"></video>
<script>
function do(){
var x = document.getElementById("videourl").value;
document.getElementById("video").src = x;
}
</script>
```

Well you can request post to a yt to audio website and etc.  etc. but it will be hard. Why not YOU figure out yourself to hide that video so only audio is audible?  Use css to turn down the video opacity.
If video doesnt work, use iframe.